# calling a global function from a local function with the same name in swift

Tags: swift

I have a global function to log messages and a class with the same function name that should call the global function. The trick is to use the module name (typically the xcode project name or target name). But how are you supposed to do this if the sourcefile is part of multiple targets?

```
func look(){
   //log stuff
}

class MyClass
{
  func look(){
    TargetName.look()
  }
}
```

Also, why doesn't String conform to the Printable protocol? Seems like an odd choice because this won't work with a String:

```
func look(value : Printable?)
{
   println(value)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you can help it, don't do the first thing. If you must, make your global functions static methods of a struct and you'll be able to reach them that way:

```
struct Logger {
    static func look(){
        //log stuff
    }
}

class MyClass {
    func look(){
        Logger.look()
    }
}
```

That *is* crazy that `String` in Swift isn't `Printable`. If you want to add it yourself, this will do it:

```
extension String: Printable {
    public var description: String { return self }
}
```

In the mean time, time to file a radar!

Comment: Ok, so I am not alone in thinking that String should be printable. I'll file a radar.

Comment: Right. It kind of doesn't need to be, since you don't need to "get a string value" of it, but then you can't use it where a `Printable` could be used.

Comment: Yeah exactly. It is not like String won't print or so. It conforms to the Streamable protocol after all. It's indeed that you can't use a String in a generic function that expects something printable. Radar filed.

Comment: Paraphrasing Apple: String behaves as intended